How to pass a disable prop in Apple Pay Stripe's button in React
I have added the Apple pay button in my application, but i want to pass a disable prop in the ButtonElement of stripe-js.
 <PaymentRequestButtonElement options={{
   paymentRequest,
   disableMultipleButtons: true,
   style: {
      paymentRequestButton: {
         type: "buy",
          theme: "dark",
          height: "48px",
          },
        },
    }} />

I am using the container of Elements to show the Button below :
    <Elements stripe={stripePromiseUS} options={STRIPE_OPTIONS}>
      {props.children}
    </Elements>

Here is my STRIPE_OPTIONS as well :
export const STRIPE_OPTIONS = {
  mode: 'setup',
  currency: 'usd',
  paymentMethodCreation: 'manual',
} as StripeElementsOptions;


When you create a paymentRequest instance[1], you can provide a list of wallets to disable[2].
  const [paymentRequest, setPaymentRequest] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stripe) {
      const pr = stripe.paymentRequest({
        country: 'US',
        currency: 'usd',
        total: {
          label: 'Demo total',
          amount: 1099,
        },
        requestPayerName: true,
        requestPayerEmail: true,
        disableWallets: ['applePay'] # add this line
      });
    }
  }, [stripe]);

If you want to disable the Request Button, unfortunately, you can't. As a workaround you can use your own button[3] and disbale/enable it as any other button in your webpage.
[1] https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=react#create-payment-request-instance
[2] https://docs.stripe.com/js/payment_request/create#stripe_payment_request-options-disableWallets
[3] https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=react#use-own-button

i don't want to disable the Apple Pay wallet option.
I want to add a disable effect or disable prop to the actual button.

No you can't disbale the request button. What you can do as a workaround, is to use your own Button (https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=react#use-own-button) and then you can disable/enable it as any other button.
